# KDE Plasma bug in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, bug-reporting, plasma, kde5

Does anybody know what the bug on the attached picture is and how it  could be fixed?

[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: What's your graphics card? Is it Nvidia? What about graphics driver you're using?

Comment: Nvidia card GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile
Graphical Driver is nvidia-driver-390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common graphics corruption issue that happens with some graphics card. I can reproduce such an issue reliably on a laptop with a broken Intel graphics adapter, so IMO this usually means that the graphics card need replacing.

See if you can clear the problem by restarting the Plasma desktop using the terminal command `killall plasmashell; kstart5 plasmashell`. If it recovers, it could be a bug in Plasma but if it doesn't - it is definitely a hardware issue.

Comment: was use command from you. It helped me. The picture is ok right now

Comment: Then its likely a bug related to suspend/resume on Nvidia - one of the following bug reports could be relevant (or all of them): https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=364766 https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344326 https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382115 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56610 , and they suggest that the problem was already fixed and you should update your OS.